# Is there a least standard model of Peano Arithmetics?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

Here's the informal part: I'm trying to get a better intuition about the differences between the standard model and the non-standard ones. Some people seem to be really good at imagining what non-standard models might look like. Models like the ultra-product $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, while somewhat easy to have as a mental model, do a poor job of refuting sentences because of Łoś's theorem (thank you for pointing this out @qiaochu-yuan). The question through which I hope to improve my intuition is: is there a 'best' model with which to refute unprovable sentences? I expect the answer to the question as asked to be 'no', perhaps because there are two unprovable sentences that hold in the standard model but whose negations contradict each other, but I find it really hard to 'see' how any first order sentence fails to hold in any non-standard model and I certainly weren't able to come up with any such sentences (except by following Gödel's incompleteness result).

### Here's the question:

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the standard (or prime) model of first order Peano Arithmetics ($PA$), that is: the least (w.r.t elementary embeddings) model such that $\mathbb{N}\vDash PA$. Is there a model $M\vDash PA$, i.e. one that satisfies Peano Arithmetics, but disagrees on every statement $\varphi$ not (dis)provable in $PA$? That is, is there an $M$ such that: $\forall \varphi.~\ PA \vdash \lnot\varphi ~\vee~ M\vDash \varphi ~\vee~ \mathbb{N}\vDash \varphi$

If the answer is yes, I realise this would still give me very little intuition about $M$, because of Tennenbaum's theorem (thank you to @noah-schweber for pointing this out). If the answer is not known, what about a *finite* set of models $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ s.t. $PA \vdash \lnot\varphi ~\vee~ M_1\vDash \varphi ~\vee \cdots \vee~ M_n\vDash\varphi$? (Completeness gives us a 'yes' for an infinite set of one model per formula.) If the answer is no, can we come up with a concrete set of true (in $\mathbb{N}$) first order formulas $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ such that none of them are disprovable, but their conjunction is disprovable?

Comment: No nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is going to be easy to describe - this is [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). Also, I think your "$\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash\varphi$" should be "$\mathsf{PA}\vdash\neg\varphi$."

Comment: Łoś's's theorem implies that $\mathbb{N}$ is elementary equivalent to its ultrapowers so the ultrapowers are no help at all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#%C5%81o%C5%9B's_theorem

Comment: Your verbal question doesn't seem equivalent to your question stated formally; I would interpret "disagrees on every statement not disprovable in PA" to mean that if $PA$ doesn't disprove $\varphi$ then $\varphi$ holds in $M$ *xor* $\varphi$ holds in $\mathbb{N}$, which is not what you've written (for two reasons). Can you clarify your question? Also, in the title did you mean to say "least nonstandard model" or maybe even "greatest nonstandard model"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I definitely meant to write 'least standard', by which I mean a model that is as different from the standard model as possible. Thank you for pointing me to the fact that ultra-powers are of no help at all, that explains a lot.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I thought you meant "least" as in "minimal" which was confusing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thank you for pointing me to Tennenbaum's theorem. I realised there's another reason why $M$ is not going to be easy to describe - if it exists, namely because all undecidability results will necessarily remain.

Comment: @Sebastiaan well *that's* not quite right - theories which are still susceptible to Godel can have computable nonstandard models, e.g. Robinson arithmetic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I meant the $M$ which would refute every non-provable sentence, i.e. we'd have ∀. ⊢¬ ∨ ⊨ ∨ ℕ⊨, and ⊢¬ is semi-decidable, but I now fail to see why this would form a contradiction even if ⊨¬ were decidable. In the case of Robinson's arithmetic (Q) and taking $M$ to be the model with Sa=a and Sb=b and standard numbers otherwise is a great mental model for that is indeed 'very non-standard', but I don't believe it satisfies ∀. Q⊢¬ ∨ ⊨ ∨ ℕ⊨. Does it? (Is there such $M$ for Q?) Thank you for pointing me to Q!